# binding windows phone c#

Tags: c#, binding, windows-phone

I need to make a binding of the Title and Link with my Xaml, this is my codebehind:

```
private void DownLoadCompleted(object sender, HtmlDocumentLoadCompleted e)
            {            
                _popVideos = new List<PopularVideos>();
                var imgs = e.Document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//img[@src]")
                    .Select(img => new
                    {
                        Link = img.Attributes["src"].Value,
                        Title = img.Attributes["alt"].Value,         

                    }).ToList();

                this.listBoxPopular.ItemsSource = imgs;
            }
```

My Xaml is this:

```
<ListBox Name="listBoxPopular">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Image Name="imagem" Source="{Binding Path=alt}"/>
                                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Title}" Tap="HyperlinkButton_Tap" Tag="{Binding Path=Url}" FontSize="30" Foreground="#FF159DDE" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: @KooKiz this code not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check to see if

> imgs

has something in it.

Comment: Yes, they upload all titles and links to the images in the variables correctly. Just missing catch just right.